# Clarification of C Operator Associativity

Tags: c

I'm reading "*The C Programming Language*" book, and I came across the following line (paraphrasing):

> "...in expressions like x = f() + g();
>
> f() maybe called before g() or vice versa. C doesn't specify the order
>   in which the operands will be evaluated..."

But, according to precedence and association rules, doesn't functions calls have highest precedence? And, since the associativity of the function call operator `()` is from "left to right", shouldn't `f()` be called before `g()` (definitely) ?

Comment: The function calls _are_ associating left to right. The function operator associates with `f` instead of `+` because of this. The next evaluation is the addition operator, and the order of evaluating _its_ operands is not specified; hence, either one could be called first.

Comment: The book is trying to explain that you shouldn't depend on side effects of one function on the other.

Comment: This isn't about precedence or associativity. The issue is that the operands of `+` are evaluated in an unspecified order. Precedence specifies which operands are associated with which operators; it doesn't specify the order in which those operands are evaluated at run time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Associativity and operator precedence only matter when you can write a construct that is ambiguous without them.  In `a + b * c`, operator precedence requires `b * c` to be evaluated first.  In `a + b + c`, associativity requires `a + b` to be evaluated first, when the program can tell the difference (such as when `a`, `b`, and `c` are floating point values).

In `f() + g()`, operator precedence does come into it a little; it says that `f` and `g` are the functions being called, as opposed to `f` and `f() + g`, which is what would happen if addition had higher precedence, and it also says that both function calls happen before the addition. Associativity, though, is *irrelevant*, because the addition is in the middle.  I don't think it's even *possible* to write the equivalent of `a + b + c` with function-call operators, because the function-call operator is asymmetric.

Neither associativity nor operator precedence controls which function call is evaluated first.  The only guarantee you have is that *one* of them is evaluated first — if there's any way for you to observe this, their execution can't be interleaved.

Answer (score 2):

> But, according to precedence and association rules, doesn't functions
>   calls have highest precedence?

The function calls have highest precedence.  It means that both f() and g() will be evaluated before "+" is evaluated.  It does not mean that f() will be evaluated before or after g().

> And, since the associativity of the function call operator () is from
>   "left to right", shouldn't f() be called before g() (definitely) ?

No, it shouldn't.  The operator () has left to right associativity.  It means that in expression `f(x)(y)` (can have it in C if the function `f` returns another function), `f(x)` is calculated first and then the resulting function is applied to `y`.  It does not mean that f() will be evaluated before or after g().

Answer (score 1):

This is neither the case of precedence or associativity in the way you refer to.
Simply, `f()` and `g()` will be evaluated in whatever order before `+` is applied and then their results will be added to produce `x`.